# How do I fill down on a FormulaR1C1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to fill down a formulaR1C1 and the code I am using works for numerical or string entries, but won't for the formula.
  This is what I have so far

```
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer
sourceCol = 4
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
Range("K11:K" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-8]="""","",R[0]C[-9]&R[0]C[-6])"
```

The last cell in column D is around 1000 and I know this works in other situations.
Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: You also need double quotes for the empty string. This works fine `"=IF(R[0]C[-8]="""","""",R[0]C[-9]&R[0]C[-6])"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've provided a couple of solutions here - using the FillDown keyword or just referencing the whole range.
Also, you didn't put enough double quotes in your formula - they all need doubling up.
In R1C1 notation you just use R to reference the same row not R[0]

- **RC** is the same row, same column.
- **R[-1]C** is the same column, -1 row
- **R1C2** is row 1, column 2

  ```
  With ActiveSheet

      ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
      '- To FillDown you can use.
      '.Range("K11").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-8]="""""""","""",RC[-9]&RC[-6])"
      '.Range(.Cells(11, 11), .Cells(rowCount, 11)).FillDown
      ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

      .Range(.Cells(11, 11), .Cells(rowCount, 11)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-8]="""""""","""",RC[-9]&RC[-6])"
  End With
  ```

Comment: Thankyou for your help, in the end I used your help to correct my sheet and it showed me recognise what was wrong with my own code.

Answer (score 0):

The above help from Darren works, however the below does too.

```
    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer
sourceCol = 4
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
Range("K11:K" & rowCount).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-8]="""","""",RC[-9]&RC[-6])"
```